# How do i make the picture fill the screen without zooming in?

Tags: html, css, image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETcXr.jpg)how do i get this image to not be zoomed in when the code is ran?

Style.css:

```
.full-img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I have tried changing the ".full img" variables, but it does not change the scale of the image.
Please ask for more code/pictures, it is my first time trying.

Comment: Try adding `object-fit: contain`

Comment: Welcome here. So, in fact, you need the image to be full screen, even if it it bigger. Do you?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following code, it should align the image without it being zoomed in.

```html
.full-img {
        background-image: url("YourPictureDirectory");
        height: 100%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
```